# Как вызвать не статическую функцию из статической?

Tags: c#, wpf, static

Как вызвать не статическую функцию из статической? Или получить доступ из статической функции к tw_tree?

> Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Window1.ReloadT()"
>   требуется ссылка на объект.

Window2

```
public void TextReload()
{
    Window1.ReloadT();
```

Window1

```
public void ReloadT()
        {
            tw_tree.ItemsSource = null;

        }
```

При изменении `public void ReloadT()`на `public static void ReloadT()` уже нельзя использовать tw_tree:

> Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Window1.tw_tree"
>   требуется ссылка на объект.

Так нормально происходит вызов статической функции:

Window2

```
Window1.SplitArguments();
```

Window1

```
public static string[] SplitArguments(){}
```

Comment: никак: статической функции не нужен объект, а не статической нужен. Если нет объекта - не статическую нельзя вызвать. Максимум можно передать в статическую функцию объект с которым идет работа. Но раз уж в статической функции используется объект - то проще сделать ее не статической

Comment: `<TreeView x:Name="tw_tree" ` - TreeView принадлежит окну Window1
Как тогда к нему обратиться из второго окна Window2?

Comment: получить в Window2 - ссылку на объект window1 и у него уже получить свойство *tw_tree* либо сразу передать это свойство

Comment: Но это уже больше похоже на совсем другой вопрос, по сравнению с первоначальным. Возможно стоит задать его отдельно с примерами xaml, и кода где и как ты собираешься что получать

Comment: @codename0082016 Очень вам советую прочитать про архитектурный паттерн MVVM, который используется при создании WPF приложений.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, например, передать экземпляр Window1 в Window2.

```
class Window2 : Window
{
    Window1 window1;

    public Window2(Window1 window1)
    {
        this.window1 = window1;
    }

    public void TextReload()
    {
        window1.ReloadT();
    }
}
```

Или создать событие, на которое подписаться в Window1.

```
class Window2 : Window
{
    public event EventHandler OnTextReload;

    public void TextReload()
    {
        OnTextReload?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

class Window1 : Window
{
    private void HandleTextReload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReloadT();
    }

    public void ShowWindow2()
    {
        var w2 = new Window2();
        w2.OnTextReload += HandleTextReload;
        w2.ShowDialog();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `window1.ReloadT();` -   

`Дополнительные сведения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.`

Comment: Это значит, что вы передаете в конструктор `Window2` `null`. Создание `Window2` внутри методов `Window1` будет выглядеть примерно так: `var w2 = new Window2(this)`

Answer (score 4):

Члены класса (поля, свойства, методы) могут быть статическими или экземплярными.
К статическим можно обращаться только в контексте класса, к экземплярным - в контексте объекта (нужно создавать объект класса и обращаться через него).

```
public class Car
{
    public static string Model; // Статическое поле
    public string Color; // Экземплярное поле
}

Car.Model = "ElectroCar"; // Обращаемся через класс Car

var myCar = new Car();
myCar.Color = "Black"; // Обращаемся через экземпляр (объект)
```

Использовать не статические члены внутри статических без инициализации объекта нельзя. Чтобы вызвать экземплярный метод, нужно либо создать объект данного класса, либо передать его из вне.

Делать члены статическими нужно в том случае, если они являются общими для всех объектов. Например, есть футболисты и мяч. Мы могли бы сделать мяч не статическим, но тогда каждый будет играть своим мячом - командной игры не получится. Мяч должен быть общим (статическим).

В Вашем случае tw_tree относится к объекту. Если Вы сделаете метод ReloadT() статическим, то при обращении к нему не получится использовать tw_tree, т.к. объект, к которому относится tw_tree не был создан.

---

Подробнее про static https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level5/5_12.php

Comment: `<TreeView x:Name="tw_tree" ` - TreeView принадлежит окну Window1
Как тогда к нему обратиться из второго окна Window2?